# Google text-to-speech API Pitch Adjustment

Tags: python-3.x, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

How can I adjust the pitch to -1.20 in this code:

```
from google.cloud import texttospeech

def text_to_wav(voice_name, text):
    language_code = "-".join(voice_name.split("-")[:2])
    text_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text=text)
    voice_params = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
        language_code=language_code, name=voice_name)

    audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
        audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)

    client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()
    response = client.synthesize_speech(
        input=text_input, voice=voice_params, audio_config=audio_config)

    filename = f"{language_code}.wav"
    with open(filename, "wb") as out:
        out.write(response.audio_content)
        print(f'Audio content written to "{filename}"')
```

The [Google Text-to-Speech documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize#audioconfig) is not pretty clear on this.  According to the documentation the 'pitch' can be adjusted in the range [-20.0, 20.0], but where can this parameter be adjusted.

Comment: @mikemaccana https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize#audioconfig

Comment: I meant in the question! But done.

Comment: From that link - `pitch` is underneath `audioConfig`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(pitch=-1.20, audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)