# How to adjust Pronunciation Pitch in Google Text to Speech API

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform

I used the Google Text2Speech API, it works well but I'd like to adjust the pitch.
I used the gTTS.

```
tts = gTTS("ご返信ありがとうございます。", lang = 'ja')
```

How should I go ahead?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're question is answered here I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66460157/google-text-to-speech-api-pitch-adjustment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/reference/rest/v1/text/synthesize#audioconfig) the text2speech API has an `AudioConfig` function where you can pass in the pitch.
The pitch can be changed in the range `[-20.0, 20.0]`. Here is a workinng example.

```
from google.cloud import texttospeech

# Instantiates a client
client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

# Set the text input to be synthesized
synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text="Hello, World!")

# Build the voice request, select the language code ("en-US") and the ssml
# voice gender ("neutral")
voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
    language_code="en-US", ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.NEUTRAL
)

# Select the type of audio file you want returned
audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
    pitch=-1.20,
    audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3
)

# Perform the text-to-speech request on the text input with the selected
# voice parameters and audio file type
response = client.synthesize_speech(
    input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config
)

# The response's audio_content is binary.
with open("output.mp3", "wb") as out:
    # Write the response to the output file.
    out.write(response.audio_content)
    print('Audio content written to file "output.mp3"')
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I used the gTTS
tts = gTTS("ご返信ありがとうございます。", lang = 'ja')
Do you know how to implement here?

Comment: No, that library uses Google translate and not Google Texttospeech as you mentioned and it does not have a pitch option.

Comment: Can you select this as the answer if it helped, so that other people can find it too.

Comment: Without the google credential, is there a way to use the api? cc @kinshukdua